# Why does decimal min value not convert to a string?

Tags: c#, .net, format, decimal

The following console app crashes:

```
decimal dec = decimal.MinValue;
string str = string.Format("{0:d}", dec);

Console.WriteLine(str);
```

The error is:

```
Format specifier was invalid.
```

Given that I'm essentially formatting a decimal as a decimal, what is wrong with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#DFormatString):

> This format is supported only for integral types.

`decimal` isn't an integral type.

The fact that the format type is *called* "decimal" is unfortunate, basically. It's because it formats integers in base 10, but it's not directly related to the `decimal` *type*.

I suspect you want `F`, `G` or `N` (or possibly something else, based on your actual requirements, which aren't really clear).

Comment: I don't really have any actual requirements.  I just spotted this and didn't know why it was happening

Comment: @pm_2: In that case, the answer is basically "because it's not meant to work" :)

Comment: That's as good a reason as any.  And you're right - the naming is definitely unfortunate

Answer (score 2):

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) about converting `decimal` values to string:

> The format parameter can be any valid standard numeric format
>   specifier except for **D**, **R**, and **X**, as well as any combination of custom
>   numeric format specifiers. If format is null or an empty string, the
>   return value of this instance is formatted with the general numeric
>   format specifier (G).

So, you can use G.

```
string str = string.Format("{0:G}", dec);
```

Read **[this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)** for more info.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
     decimal dec = decimal.MinValue;
     string str = string.Format("F: {0}", dec);

     Console.WriteLine(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the format identifier {0:d}
Try

```
string.Format("{0}", dec)
```

Answer (score 0):

From [the MSDN help for `Decimal.ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fzeeb5cd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The format parameter can be any valid standard numeric format specifier except for D, R, and X

And in [the help for Standard Numeric Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), it says of the `d` format:

> Supported by: Integral types only.

Answer (score 0):

Because the format specifier doesn't do what you think. It is for integers only, despite the name `Decimal`. See the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for the full details.